# RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 1 in Autodesk forge viewer

Tags: webgl, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm getting many warnings with: `RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 1`.

[image]

The count increases when I move the mouse across the model. I tried to google it but didn't find anything relevant.

When I comment out these two lines (they're called after geometry was loaded), I get only 19 of these warnings:

```
    viewer.setQualityLevel(false, false);    // turn off antialiasing and shadows 
    viewer.prefs.tag('ignore-producer');    // disable lighting
```

Could be that it's related? Is there a way to have these two lines and not all of these warnings?

Comment: Not sure how to get rid of those, I'm checking with our development team and will let you know ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to remove that warning at the moment. This may be fixed when the viewer API is moving to an higher version of three.js, which may happen in a while.

Your best workaround at the moment if this bothers you is to filter warnings in the chrome console or use another browser, I don't see those in firefox ...